# Acer Aspire Easystore H340 Has No Power

Tags: power, acer-aspire

So, I turned off my [Aspire Easystore H340](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16859321013) last night now it has no power (I know its over 10 years old). 
No lights, fans, etc when pressing the power button.
I took it apart and put back to together cleaning it out. Making sure all the connections are snug and no dust in there. Still nothing.
None of the capacitors on the motherboard or back-plain look swollen or burst.
I tested the power supply with the old [paper clip method](http://www.wikihow.com/Check-a-Power-Supply) and the PSU turned on just fine.

I just can't figure out what to do next.
Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Same situation here. Any luck with yours?

Comment: I ended up buying a PSU tester on Amazon (https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00Q8SUYHW) and it was dead. Seems to have killed the motherboard too. I cut my losses and built a small server with new hardware